# Webpack devtool="(none)" breaks my code

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

I'm using webpack 3.10 and I've got different webpack configs for dev/prod. Now in my prod config "devtool = "(none)"" is set, while in my dev config it is "eval-source-map".

Sadly using the prod config, my bundle is non functional. While using the dev config everything is working fine.
I tried around a bit and every setting that is flagged as "production: yes" on in the webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ breaks my code.

Can anyone explain the exact difference between the settings. Is there anything else that changes (minifying/uglyfying whatever)?

Kind regards.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid syntax: `"devtool = "(none)""` Also, I think you're maybe taking the documentation too literally, `(none)` should just be `null` or an empty string `''`. It would be helpful to see more of your actual config code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0lmjlqmj7

I created the 2 webpack files as im using them in this sandbox. There's really not much difference. Also as I said any other production: yes value for the devtool parameter (like "source-map" as in the sandbox) breaks it.

Comment: Okay. Parts of my (/our) code weren't minification save at all. Checking react components' types as string. So the minification just broke it. It's fine now. Webpack is all good :)

Comment: iI think t should be devtool = false in webpack 5 and before that it should be devtool="none"

Answer (score 29):

In webpack `5.2.0`, you can declare the config as `devtool: false` in production for the `(none)` functionality.

NOTE: If you have `mode: "development"` and you do not mention `devtool` in your webpack config, the devtool defaults to `eval`.

Comment: FYI: This feature is not exclusive to webpack v5. It's also there in v4.

Comment: `devtool: false` doesn't work for me in webpack 5.

Comment: Use ```--no-devtool``` instead when using webpack-cli

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use it. To make it work, you shouldn't specify a `devtool` key. Not a null value or `(none)`, you simply shouldn't have the `devtool` key on your configuration.

```
{
  ...
  plugins: [],
  optimization: {}
  ...
}
```

Without any `devtool` in between.

Comment: Not true in case of `mode: development`. In development mode, the `devtool` defaults to `eval`.

Comment: Well, there's a boolean option. Simply can set it to `false` which will be very useful in programmatical usage of webpack.